# Probability density of $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)^2$

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution

Similar to the derivation of the probability of the chi-squared distribution, say we have continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $Y = X^2$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. What is the probability density of $Y$ in this case?

This should seemingly be trivial but I cannot reproduce the result I have found in my lecture notes. The expected result is:

$$
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma y}} \exp(-\frac{y + \mu^2}{2 \sigma^2}) \left[\exp(\frac{\mu \sqrt{y}}{\sigma^2}) + \exp(-\frac{\mu \sqrt{y}}{\sigma^2})\right]
$$

but I don't get that at all, here's what I have tried so far:

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} (P_X[X \leq \sqrt{y}] - P_X[X \leq -\sqrt{y}])
$$

where:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy} P_X[X \leq \sqrt{y}] &=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \frac{d}{dy}\exp(-\frac{(\sqrt{y} - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} (\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}})(-\frac{\sqrt{y} - \mu}{\sigma^2}) \exp(-\frac{(\sqrt{y} - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2})
\end{align*}

and at this point it's already clear that this will not work out since there are is going to be an unwanted factor $-(\sqrt{y} - \mu)/\sigma^2$ in in the final expression for $f_Y(y)$.

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT:

I really screwed up here, as gt6989b rightly pointed out I forgot an integral so the second part should really be:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy} P_X[X \leq \sqrt{y}] &=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \frac{d}{dy} \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{y}} \exp(-\frac{(t - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}) dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} (\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}})\exp(-\frac{(\sqrt{y} - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2})
\end{align*}

Which works out I think.

Comment: Shouldn't you be integrating instead of differentiating?

Comment: Actually I think I should be doing neither. I tried adapting this from the derivation of the chi-squared distribution and there the differentiation "cancels" the integral. I think I have just forgotten the integral here and that might solve it.

Comment: The $k=1$ case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).